# Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin after redirect from foreign page

Tags: security, browser

**Settings**
Header(Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin)

**What I would like to do**
I got a main page which triggers a popup for login. Login page is not in same origin. After successful login popup location redirects to my domain which is now in same origin.

**Problem**
I could not get access to window.opener from popup, so I could not reload main page; its still not working although popup and parent site are in same origin now.

**What I tested**
I tried to set some more headers like
Header(Origin: https://example.com)
but problem persists.

Any ideas? I dont want to disable coop...